# What are the differences between UL1581 and UL2556 for VW-1 (Vertical Flame Test)?

Tags: ul, iec

In IEC62368-1, it's stated:

> Wire complying with UL 2556 VW-1 is considered to comply with these
> requirements.

I've asked a manufacturer if he could meet these requirements and he answered that he cannot comply with UL2556 VW-1 but with UL1581 1080.

I could find the following online:

> UL 1581 section 1080 - reference to standard UL 2556, section 9.4
> (VW-1 Flame Test)

([Source](https://www.sab-cable.com/fileadmin/user_upload/pdf/catalog_gb/kapitel_N/Flamability_tests_for_electrical_cables_UL_1581_-_1080.pdf))

So my questions are :

- Is "UL1581 1080" just a reference to "UL2556 VW-1" test?
- If a cable meets "UL1581 1080", does it automatically meet "UL2556 VW-1"?

Comment: Did you not consider that a follow up call to the supplier might have resolved this?

Comment: Did you consider if I'm asking this here it has not?

Comment: So, what was their response and, if their response was insufficient or lacking, you should seek out a different supplier.

Comment: I know I could get a better manufacturer but it's not that simple. Anyway, I'm genuinely interested in getting an answer about the differences between the 2 standards.